# nginx 403 when serving static files + reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-403, static-files

I'm trying to serve a node app through nginx, but first attempt to serve static files that may be in a `/public` folder. I've got that much working -- but when accessing `domain.tld/` or the index of static folders, I get a 403; `directory index of "/var/www/domain.tld/" is forbidden`. All the permissions seem to correct, so I'm rather confused.

This is my server block;

```
server {
    server_name domain.tld;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain.tld/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        access_log off;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
 }
```

Accessing any random page (including assumed sub-directories) properly proxies to the node app. In the case of the root / and root of any existing static directory, however, 403.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the directory exists, and therefore the `try_files` check

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
```

succeeds. But there is no directory index file (typically `index.html`, see [index](http://nginx.org/r/index)), and `autoindex` is not turned on either (see [autoindex](http://nginx.org/r/autoindex)).

Depending on what you want to happen, consider the following options:

- Leave it as is (and may be tune which index files are used).
- Always pass directories to a backend. Remove `$uri/` from `try_files` to do it, i.e.:

  ```
  location /
      root /var/www/domain.tld/public;
      try_files $uri @proxy;
  }
  ```
- Check for a particular index file via `try_files` (and the request will go to a backend if it's not found):

  ```
  location /
      root /var/www/domain.tld/public;
      try_files $uri $uri/index.html @proxy;
  }
  ```
- Enable `autoindex`:

  ```
  location /
      root /var/www/domain.tld/public;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
      autoindex on;
  }
  ```

Comment: Perfect! I went with the second solution you suggested. Thanks.